# Reading from a list in a text file, ripping certain a line and showing in listbox, Visual studio 2010

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops, text-files

I'm creating a barcode scanning program in visual studio 2010 using vb.

I have come on pretty far, but have seemed to get stuck at this little problem.

I have a text file saved and a data in it displayed like this:

```
0001#Unsmoked Middle Bacon
0002#Smoked Middle bacon
0003#Unsmoked Bits
0004#Smoked Bits
0005#Unsmoked Back
0006#Smoked Back
0007#Unsmoked Streaky
0008#Smoked Streaky
```

I have no problem reading and splitting the strings with #, and I can populate 2 listboxes, 1 displaying the 4 digit code, and the other the product name. (this was just a test scenario)

What i really want to do, is search the file for a variable that is a user inputed number such as "0004" and this would display back to me "smoked bits".

I think i am wanting to read down line by line, until it hits the right number, then read across maybe using a substr? You guys could probably help me alot here.

```
While Not sreader.EndOfStream                               
                lineIn = sreader.ReadLine()
                Dim elements() As String = Nothing                      
                elements = lineIn.Split("#")
                lstProdTest.Items.Add(elements(0))
                lstProdName.Items.Add(elements(1))
                PLUnumber(index) = elements(0) 
                itemName(index) = elements(1)
                numProds = numProds + 1
                index = index + 1
            End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Origin says, providing this file isnt so large as to consume too much memory, reading the data once is the way to go:

```
Private _barcodes As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'EDIT forgot to initialize _barcodes:
    _barcodes = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    For Each line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\path\to\file.txt")
        Dim data = line.Split("#"c)
        _barcodes.Add(CInt(data(0)), data(1))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim input As String = InputBox("type the barcode to test, eg 0004:")
    Dim key As Integer = CInt(input)
    'if you entered 0004 then this will display Smoked Bits
    If _barcodes.ContainsKey(key) Then
        MessageBox.Show(_barcodes(key))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Key not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note this is just a quick example and would require error handling to be added (for missing file, incorrect format of data etc)

If the amount of data is huge then consider a database instead, sqlite would be a simple option

Comment: I can see how this works now :)

I seem to be springing an error on form load though.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
        _barcodes.Add(CInt(data(0)), data(1))

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you :) With a bit of tweaking into the bigger program it now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As they say, premature optimization is the root of all evils. Instead of reading your file each time you need an item description, you should read the file in once (at the start of the application), store it in memory (perhaps as a `Dictionary(of Integer, String)`) and then reference this when trying to get the description for an item.

You could of course go further and create a custom class to store additional information about each entry.